Is $(tW_{t^2})$ a Markov Process?
As in the question, is $X_t = tW_{t^2}$ Markov process with respect to the filtration generated by $X$?
My attempt. Filtration generated by $X_t$, so $\sigma(X_s, s \le t)$, is the same as the filtration $\sigma(W_{s^2}, s \le t) = \mathcal{F}_{s^2}^W$
We want to show that there exists a measurable function h such that $\mathbb{E}\left(f\left(tW_{t^2} | \mathcal{F}_{s^2}^W\right)\right) = h(sW_{s^2})$, so
$$\mathbb{E}\left(f\left(tW_{t^2} | \mathcal{F}_{s^2}^W\right)\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(f\left(t(W_{t^2}-W_{s^2}) + tx\right)\right)_{|x = W_{s^2}}$$
I've managed to transform it into the form of
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f\left(\frac{t}{s}z\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s^2(t^2-s^2)}}\exp{\left(-\frac{(z-y)^2}{2s^2(t^2-s^2)}\right)}\hbox{d}z_{|y = sW_{s^2}} = h(sW_{s^2})$$
is it correct?

Put $X_t = t W_{t^2}$. Let $\sigma(\xi)$ be the smallest sigma-algebra, containing $\xi$. Note that $\sigma(X_t) = \sigma(W_{t^2})$ - it's obvious if $t=0$ and if $t > 0$. Further, by definition of Markov process, we want to show that if $0 \le s_1 < s_2 < \ldots < s_m < s < t$ then
$$\mathbf{E}(f(X_t) | X_{s}, X_{s_m}, \ldots, X_{s_1}) = \mathbf{E}(f(X_t) | X_{s}). \quad (*) $$
for all bounded continious functions $f$. Put $t^2 = \tilde{t}, s^2 = \tilde{s}, s_i^2 = \tilde{s}_i, 1 \le i \le m$. We have $$\mathbf{E}(f(X_t) | X_{s}, X_{s_m}, \ldots, X_{s_1})= \mathbf{E}(f(t W_{t^2}) | W_{s^2}, W_{s_m^2}, \ldots, W_{s_1^2}) = \mathbf{E}(g(W_{t^2}) | W_{s^2}, W_{s_m^2}, \ldots, W_{s_1^2}) = \mathbf{E}(g(W_{\tilde{t}}) | W_{\tilde{s}}, W_{\tilde{s_m}}, \ldots, W_{\tilde{s_1}}) \quad (**) $$
We know that Wiener process is Markov process, because it has independent increments. Thus
$$ \mathbf{E}(g(W_{\tilde{t}}) | W_{\tilde{s}}, W_{\tilde{s_m}}, \ldots, W_{\tilde{s_1}}) =  \mathbf{E}(g(W_{\tilde{t}}) | W_{\tilde{s}}).$$
Taking $(**)$ into account, we get:
$$ \mathbf{E}(f(X_t) | X_{s}, X_{s_m}, \ldots, X_{s_1})=\mathbf{E}(g(W_{\tilde{t}}) | W_{\tilde{s}}) = \mathbf{E}(g(W_{t^2}) | W_{s^2}) =\mathbf{E}(f(X_t)| X_s).$$
So $(*)$ is proved.

Thank you for your answer, I see we can just use the fact that Brownian motion is a Markov process. Could you also tell if my approach is correct?

@Barabara You write "We want to show ...". It's not very convenient definition of Markov process. Further, "I've managed to transform" - so, the answer depends on what you want. If you want your soluton to be checked, then the full solution should be written. If you want a more consise solution, then it's above

The time changed Brownian motion $W_{t^2}$ is a martingale w.r.t. the filtration $({\cal F}^W_{t^2})_{t\ge 0}$ and has quadratic
variation $t^2\,.$
Therefore,
$$
B_t:=\int_0^t \frac1s\,dW_{s^2}
$$
is a continuous martingale with quadratic variation $t\,.$ In other words, $B_t$ is a Brownian motion. Obviously, this satisfies
$$
W_{t^2}=\int_0^ts\,dB_s\,.
$$
Integration by parts then yields
\begin{align}
X_t=tW_{t^2}=t\int_0^ts\,dB_s\stackrel{\text{int. by parts}}=\int_0^ts^2\,dB_s+\int_0^t\underbrace{\int_0^us\,dB_s}_{\textstyle\frac1uX_u}\,du\,.
\end{align}
This can be written as an SDE for a time-inhomogeneous Markov process:
\begin{align}
dX_t=t^2\,dB_t+\frac1t X_t\,dt\,.
\end{align}

YES, provided $W$ is a Markov process with $W_0=0$. In that case $\mathcal F^X_t=\mathcal F^W_{t^2}$ for each $t\ge 0$. If $0<s<t$ then
$$
E[f(X_t)\mid\mathcal F^X_s]=E[f(tW_{t^2})\mid\mathcal F^W_{s^2}]=g(W_{s^2})=h(X_s),
$$
where $g$ (coming from the Markov property of $W$) may depend on $s$ and $t$, and $h(x):=g(x/s)$ also depends on $s$ and $t$.
You seem to be assuming (implicitly) that $W$ is a Wiener process, but that hypothesis is unnecessary; only the Markov property of $W$ is needed.
